# Convert column values to columns

Tags: sql

Currently the database looks like below :

[image: Current data structure]

I am trying to convert it as below :

[image: Expected data structure]

The best way I could come up with was a SQL pivot. But that groups the Product ID and gives only one of the three 330 rows that we see above. I am not able to think of any other way to approach this. If anyone could think of any way to solve could you please share your thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select productid,
       max(case when description = 'Part No' then unitdesc end) as partno,
       . . .  -- and so on for the other columns
from t
group by productid;
```

EDIT:

I see, you have multiple rows per product.  You have a problem, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  That is not obvious.

So, the following will create single rows, but not necessarily combined as you would like:

```
select productid,
       max(case when description = 'Part No' then unitdesc end) as partno,
       . . .  -- and so on for the other columns
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by productid, description order by productid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by productid, seqnum;
```

If you have a column that does capture the ordering of the rows, then use that column in the `order by`.

Comment: This is exactly what I had. But the problem is I need the Product IDs ungrouped so that I see all the Part Nos linked to it.

Comment: @Pradeep . . . You should have included your query in the question.  In any case, you can get the multiple rows.  The problem is that you are relying on an implicit ordering of the rows in the table, and SQL tables have no implicit ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve the corresponding values:

```
select
  p.product_id,
  n.unit_desc as part_no,
  d.unit_desc as description,
  pn.unit_desc as price_now,
  u.unit_desc as unit
from (select distinct product_id from t) p
left join (select product_id, description from t where description = 'Part No') n
left join (select product_id, description from t where description = 'Description') d
left join (select product_id, description from t where description = 'Price Now') pn
left join (select product_id, description from t where description = 'Unit') u
```